# E: Unable to locate package code

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm trying to install VSCode using my Linux terminal and the command `sudo apt install code` but it's giving me this error instead:

```
E: Unable to locate package code
```

I've tried running `sudo apt update` but I still keep getting the same error. Please how do I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The VScode documentation: [Visual Studio Code on Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux)

```
sudo apt install wget gpg apt-transport-https
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
sudo install -o root -g root -m 644 microsoft.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/microsoft-archive-keyring.gpg
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/microsoft-archive-keyring.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install code
```

Via snap:

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install code --classic
sudo snap run code
```